# ANDROID: Linear>Relative>LinearLayout>Table>SeekBar too small

Tags: android, android-layout

in a quite complex Layout I need to have 4 SeekBars and one Button in a row. The ratio of the space should result in 7:1.

The layout tree looks like that:

```
<LinearLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

           <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <SeekBar  
                          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
           </TableRow>
                    <!--- 3 more SeekBar, one table row each -->
     </TableLayout>
     <TableLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:layout_width="0dp" 
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:text="O_" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Sorry if that code looks messy but I hope you get the basic idea as I think the problem will just be a simple value to edit.

As you can see on the picture, the layout bounds get drawn correctly to the button, but the SeekBars just stays tiny. 
[image: As you can see on the picture, the layout bounds get drawn correctly to the button, but the SeekBars just stay tiny.]

Thanks a lot in advance for you help, I hope I described the problem enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the following to `seekbar` and it should work fine

`android:layout_weight="1"`

here is the complete code that i tested and worked fine

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
            <!--- 3 more SeekBar, one table row each -->
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="O_" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ahhhh how could I not think of that? Thanks so freaking much!!!
This answer brought us the world piece.

Comment: I had a problem as well using a seekbar inside a horizontal LinearLayout. Setting match_parent for the width, it would fill up the screen to the right, even if there were views after it, and it caused the height to expand improperly. Setting the weight to 1  and with width to 0dp fixed the problem!!